# How to replace row values in a DataFrame/Series on the basis of a condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am preparing a model for the titanic shipwreck dataset. I am trying to fill the missing age of male and female members as 31 and 28 years respectively.

I tried this code for filling missing age of male passengers

```
if data[data.Sex=='male'].Age.isna():
     
    data['Age'] = 31
```

and got the following error,

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might want to do a Python/Pandas Tutorial first. Because that is not really like pandas works.

Answer (score 0):

```
if data[data.Sex=='male'].Age.isna():
 
    data['Age'] = 31
```

There are multiple errors:

1. `data[data.Sex=='male'].Age.isna()`
   Returns a series of booleans like: (True, False, False, True) What do you expect the `if statement` to do? If means, do something IF the following is True. Here it gets not a True or False but a series of those.

It can't handle that which is why you get the error: *ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*

2. Even if it would work, both lines would be processed independently of each other. Because `data[data.Sex=='male'].Age.isna()` has no connection with `data['Age'] = 31`
   Even if the `if` statement would be `True` the `data['Age'] = 31` would set all ages to 31 not only the missing ones. I don't think thats what you want to do.

**Solution:**

To achive what you most likely want to do you can use:

```
data.loc[( (data.Sex=='male') & (data.Age.isna()) )] = 31
```

Also so that you get the if statement to return True instead of the error, use:

`any(data[data.Sex=='male'].Age.isna())` or `all(data[data.Sex=='male'].Age.isna())` depending on what you want to achive.